# how to design responsive image button & layout by using android studio?

Tags: android-layout

i am new to android development . I designed one parking app , but the layout is not responsive to all mobile devices.
I tried to make responsive image buttons by using 9patch png images & by taking different drawable folder(hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi) . But both are not working for large screen devices.

This is one sample xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/exit1"
        android:onClick="on_Bexit"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/home0"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/home0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/home1"
        android:onClick="on_Bhome0"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/car"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/c4"
        android:onClick="on_Bcar"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/bike"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/bike" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bike"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/b3"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="on_Bbike"
        android:layout_above="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="ENTRY   "
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#8dacbe"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/car"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView6" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bike_count"
        android:text="90"
        android:textColor="#140441"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bike"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/exit"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/exit"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/car_count"
        android:text="120"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textColor="#140441"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/car"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bike_count"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bike_count" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/T_areadis"
        android:hint="Parking area id and name"
        android:textColor="#8dacbe"
        android:text="kharghar"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="PAGE"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textColor="#005384"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:fontFamily="@string/abc_action_bar_home_description"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/car_count"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/car_count" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please kindly help me out.

Comment: _"But both are not working for large screen devices."_ - in what way are they not working?

Answer (score 0):

1. Large screen devices use xxhdpi.
2. How to has equal width

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/exit"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter"
           android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           android:onClick="on_Bexit"
           android:src="@drawable/icon_login" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="ENTRY   "
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
           android:textColor="#8dacbe"
           android:textSize="35dp"
           android:textStyle="bold" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/home0"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter"
           android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           android:onClick="on_Bhome0"
           android:src="@drawable/icon_login" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/bike_count"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="90"
           android:textColor="#140441"
           android:textSize="30dp"
           android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/car"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter"
           android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           android:onClick="on_Bcar"
           android:src="@drawable/icon_login" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/car_count"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="120"
           android:textColor="#140441"
           android:textSize="30dp"
           android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/bike"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter"
           android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           android:onClick="on_Bbike"
           android:src="@drawable/icon_login" />
       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/T_areadis"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:hint="Parking area id and name"
           android:text="kharghar"
           android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
           android:textColor="#8dacbe"
           android:textSize="30dp" />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```